# how do i insert math quadratic equation/formula in database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, math

I want to create online math quiz and all questions and answers and correct answer are store in the mysql database. I have quadratic equation like.

[image]

now how do i insert exactly same question formula or equation  with their answer in the database table column and database column type is `blob`.

**Database Column After Inserted Formula or Equations**

[image]

**Inseet Query**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
$class1=$_POST['class1'];   
$subjects1=$_POST['subjects1'];
$lessons=$_POST['lessons'];
$marks=$_POST['marks'];

$length = count($_POST['ques']);
for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++)
{
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO quiz 
VALUES ('','$class1','$subjects1','$lessons',
'".$_POST['ques'][$i]."','".$_POST['ans1'][$i]."',
'".$_POST['ans2'][$i]."','".$_POST['ans3'][$i]."','".$_POST['ans4'][$i]."',
'".$_POST['corans'][$i]."','$marks')") or die ("quiz insert query");    

 }
 }
```

**can i use MathJax is an open source JavaScript for quiz and it will work for php and mysql databasee query?**

Comment: Possibly using MathML - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML

Comment: @MarkBaker is that possible php mysql merge with `http://www.mathjax.org/ MathJax is an open source JavaScript display engine for mathematics that works in all browsers.`

Comment: It's not something I've tried; but it should be perfectly acceptable to store MathML in the database, and all you then need is the means to render it on your questions page (MathJax shoul dprovide that), and edit it when you set the questions.

Comment: How does the user input the formula into your program in the first place? If it's through LaTeX or similar markup, store the markup.

Comment: @joni i will paste formula in the textarea?

Comment: And how does that work? A textarea permits only plain text.

Comment: @joni should i use textbox intead of textarea?

Comment: I fail to see where the core of your question lies. MathJax is for math rendering, using data formats like LaTeX, MathML or similar as input. There might be JavaScript formula editors out there which might be building on that, or not. But is *editing* math in JavaScript your question? If so, then all that stuff about databases is irrelevant. If your concern is about databases, then I'm confused by the direction: answers go from the client to the database, but MathJax goes from data to a client rendering. Please clarify.

Comment: @mvg no i want to insert math formula or equation in the database exactly same a i display example picture instead use of formula or equation image in the website.. i have more 1000 maths mcqs i can't convert all of my questions into images?

Comment: Refer to [How to save math equations to database..?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32579105/6521116)

Answer (score 4):

Your question is still pretty unclear to me, but I'll try to answer as best as I can. The way I understand it now, someone (a teacher) is composing a question, including the formulas, and many other people (the students) should choose the correct answer from a fixed set of alternatives. So only the author of the question has to get the math formula into the system, while the students must see the nice math rendering.

You write (in a comment) that you intend to paste the equation into the web page. I don't know from what other application you intend to paste it.

## Entering LaTeX notation manually

I do know that most professional mathematicians will probably feel most at home in writing down an equation the way LaTeX understands them. And that is one of several possible input formats for MathJax. In the case of your formula, the LaTeX markup could look like this:

```
f(x) = a_0 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(
  a_n\cos\frac{n\pi x}{L} +
  b_n\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}
\right)
```

So one possible approach would be providing a text area where users could enter markup like this. Then you could store that markup in just that form inside the database, and use MathJax to render a nice formula in the resulting HTML page.

## Using an external editor

If you insist on using an external editor to compose formulas, you'll have to provide more details. What editor(s) do you have in mind? In what formats do they offer their documents on the clipboard? Can they export to a file in any established format for math notation?

The most likely solution would be getting that external editor to somehow export a MathML file. That file (which is an XML format) could then be uploaded (using a file upload form element) and stored in the database, and either embedded directly in HTML, thus relying on the math rendering modern browsers provide out of the box, or again be used as the input to MathJax to increase portability with older or misbehaving browsers.