# How to save math equations to database..?

Tags: html, asp.net, database, math, editor

My website is in Asp.net and I am using MySql as database. I have some sample math papers in Microsoft office word. I want any kind of HTML input tool like textbox or editor so that I can copy office word formulas direct to editor and that I have to save into database

Example:

1. Solve the inequation and represent the solution on the number line:  (7x-5)/(2x+14)   ≥ 1 1/4 (x ≥ -7), x ∈ R.   [x ≥ 5]

Consider the above question if I do copy paste into textbox some of symbols it takes as garbage..

Comment: check this link https://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: I have checked and using right now same but i have problem with that is.. It is not able to copy. It need to export as png. and i not want that..

Comment: thanx for suggestion.. But please if you have any alternative tell me. I w ant to copy microsoft formulas as is to edior.

Comment: How you are exporting in png....

Comment: there is an option in that editor "Save as" you can save it in any image format

Comment: sorry for the confusion i was using mathml Editor. I will check this mathjax and let you know about it. and thank you very much. for comment

Comment: Ok,,,and to export in PNG you can use PHP image library

Comment: mathjax is for displaying maths formula on  webpage i not want to d o that.. I want to copy my microsoft office word formulas to any kind of input tool and save it to database

Comment: no no i not want to export it to png or image.. I create pdf of that questions by taking all selected questions from database.. but my problem is not that.

Comment: Have you checked live demo....

Comment: I checked documentation of it. and also in documentation there are some sample examples.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Could the use of a math editor, like this one, could help you? http://sharemath.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save math equation into database, a text format is more applicable. You can convert it to any format.

Refer to this question [understanding a mathematica equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84326/understanding-a-mathematica-equation) on [mathematica.stackexchange.com](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com), there are many math formula with many specified chars and in text format.

There are many ways to render a text formula.

1. `<script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-19">n(r) = \frac{2\pi r^2}{\sqrt{3}}</script>`, the math equation is with text format `n(r) = \frac{2\pi r^2}{\sqrt{3}}` in latex format.
2. `<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mi>n</mi><mo stretchy="false">(</mo><mi>r</mi><mo stretchy="false">)</mo><mo>=</mo><mfrac><mrow><mn>2</mn><mi>&#x03C0;</mi><msup><mi>r</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow><msqrt><mn>3</mn></msqrt></mfrac></math>` is in mathml format.
3. You also can use a render in your server or a client render to render the text formual to a image, like `<img src="https://example.com/?e=n(r) = \frac{2\pi r^2}{\sqrt{3}}">`

So you can choose a common formula format, when use it you can render it directly or convert it to other format, or image.