# Save math formula into database

Tags: java, database, math, formula

I've got a database of questions in SQlite that I read them from my java code. My questions are questions of Mathematics and I provide them as a text in the database.

My problem is that in several questions I want to include mathematical symbols and operators that I can include with my keyboard and provide it as a text.

Is there a way to include my math symbols inside the database?

Or I have to do it from my code?

Comment: Refer to [How to save math equations to database..?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32579105/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

I see two options

**1. Unicode**

In Sqlite choose text type that stores unicode. In unicode, you have plenty of math symbols https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode
If unicode does not contain symbol you need, you are out of luck, and you need some other solution

To store text as unicode, see http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19397231/1849837

**2. Math language**

Store equations in some math language that is able to describe equations. In this solution, in order for your equations to look nice you will need something that translate quation description (pure text) into equation image.

If you ask this question on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ I am sure you will be advised component and data format that fit your needs.

Comment: He can define his own encoding for one column in which he has mathematical symbols.