# Is it possible to store Math expressions in a database with EF C# Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, math

Is it possible to store Math expressions in a database with EF C# Linq. I have a Category class that is represented as a table in the database. I want to be able to add, update and delete the math expression. The math expression is going to be used when calculating a price for that specific category. It will be associated with category. Is it possible to parse the expression if I store it as string or is there a better way?

Comment: What does the "math expression" look like?

Comment: `initialCost + hourly/Price * amount of hours`

Comment: I'd say just store it as a string, no matter how you represent this expression. You'll need to make your own "domain specific language", and you can choose if you represent it like that or as XML or JSON or something else. There's nothing built into either SQL Server or C# or LINQ to help you with this.

Comment: Ok. Then i know. I could build a regular expression to break apart the string and use the expression. Thanks!

Comment: By expression you mean C# expression trees? Like `myTable.Categories.Select(c => initialCost + hourly/c.Price * amount of hours)`?

Comment: no I didn't, but I am thankful for enlightening me of the possibility.

Comment: Refer to [How to save math equations to database..?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32579105/6521116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Eval Expression.NET](https://github.com/zzzprojects/Eval-Expression.NET)

Related Link: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57928/arithmetic-operation-from-string

Comment: @AllramEst: This definitely solves the problem, but please be very careful when using this. *This is essentially arbitrary code execution.*

Comment: @AllramEst: As an example, someone could use the expression `Enumerable.Repeat(1, 1).Select(_ => { File.Delete(...); return 1; }).Count()` and run all kinds of evil code.

Comment: be aware that Eval Expression.NET is paid library